# Simple ANTLR grammar hiccup trying to deal with quotes

Tags: antlr4

I want to parse lists of "[Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) atoms", i.e. simple strings which in some cases have to be put into single quotes lest they be confused with variable names or integers, to allow inclusion of blanks as well as to allow inclusion of single quotes themselves.

An input file containing numbers followed by a olon followed by a Prolog list of atoms shall be processed.

The input file may for example be:

```
1: [ foo, bar ]
2: [ alpha, 'THIS IS VARIABLE NAMES WITH BLANKS THUS QUOTES' , '_also_a_variable_name' ]
3: [ empty_atom_follows, '' ]
4: []
5: [ 'the above is an empty list' ]
6: [ 'single quotes \' are possible' ]
```

I'm trying this in IntellijIDEA which has a nice plugin where you can experiment with the grammer and get immediate feedback as to whether lexing/parsing succeeds not (invaluable!).

The grammar so far is as follows.

Note that I cannot discard the blanks because they may appear inside quoted atoms, where they are significant.

```
grammar simple;

file : line ( EOL line )* EOL? ;

line : BLANK* uinteger BLANK* COLON BLANK* list_of_atom BLANK* ;

empty_list   : '[' BLANK* ']' ;

list_of_atom : empty_list
             | '[' BLANK* atom (BLANK* ',' BLANK* atom)* BLANK* ']'
             ;

uinteger : DIGIT+ ;

atom : fused_atoms
     | quoted_atom
     | unquoted_atom
     | empty_atom
     ;

empty_atom    : '\'\'';  // literally: '', no blanks
unquoted_atom : LOWER atom_char_not_needing_quotation* ;
quoted_atom   : '\'' atom_char_any+ '\'' ;
fused_atoms   : quoted_atom ( quoted_atom )+ ;

atom_char_not_needing_quotation : LOWER | UPPER | DIGIT | USCORE ;
atom_char_any                   : LOWER | UPPER | DIGIT | USCORE | DASH | BLANK | quote_escape ;
quote_escape                    : ('\\\'') ;

LOWER  : [a-z] ;
UPPER  : [A-Z] ;
DIGIT  : [0-9] ;
USCORE : '_' ;
DASH   : '-' ;
DOT   : '.' ;
SIGN  : '+' | '-' ;
COLON : ':' ;
EOL    : [\r\n];
BLANK  : [\t ];
```

I'm hitting a bit of a phenomenon for the `fused_atoms`.

In Prolog there are (at least) two ways to insert a single quote into an atom:

Escape it with backspace:

```
?- X = 'a\'b'.
X = 'a\'b'.
```

Escape it with single quote:

```
?- X = 'a''b'.
X = 'a\'b'.
```

In order to get the same effect, I want to leave open the possibility of considering an atom as "several fused atoms" (really, concatenated quoted atoms), i.e.

```
'a''b'
```

shall be parsed as two quoted atoms side-by-side, grouped into a "fused atom". My idea is that through postprocessing I will join the two strings with a single quote in between.

Apparently ANTLR doesn't like my rule.

If I give it

```
1 : [ 'a''b' ,  'a\'\'\'b'   , '\' ', ' ']
```

it gets confused:

```
line 1:8 no viable alternative at input ''a'''
```

and the parse tree indicates a failure as it tries to grab the two single quotes at once:

[image: Parse tree detail]

What's going wrong?

Comment: `atom_char_any` can't derive `empty_atom`. Add in `| empty_atom` to the `atom_char_any` rule, it then works.

Comment: @kaby76 Thank you but that's not it. I don't want the "empty atom", written `''` (two quotes in insolation) to be a _part_ of a nonempty atom. The empty atom is a special atom, same as an empty string.

Comment: Then, use the literal `''` itself. But, you defined a token type `''` in the combined grammar (RHS of empty_atom). The lexer always operates independently from the parser, tokenizing the input before parsing, and always choosing the token with the greatest length. In your example `'a''b'`, the lexer will return `'` `a` `''` `b` `'`, not `'` `a` `'` `'` `b` `'` as what you want in order to follow the derivation `fused_atoms => quoted_atom quoted_atom`. This is a mistake most people make: the parser does not influence the lexer. Always print out the token stream to verify it is what you expect.

Comment: @kaby76 Yes... I get it now I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you want to parse a String (ATOM) as a single token rather than a bunch of individual tokens that are all brought together in a parser Rule:

a Lexer rule:

```
ATOM: '\'' ('\\\'' | '\'\'' | ~'\'')* '\'';
```

will handle both "'" (slash quote) and "''" (quote quote) representations of an embedded quote.  A quick replace all on the token text will take care of post-processing those to a single embedded ' quote.

In your comment you mention unquoted `ATOM`s.  You could just amend your ATOM Lexer rule like so: (based on the rules in your question)

```
ATOM:
    '\'' ('\\\'' | '\'\'' | ~'\'')* '\''
    | LOWER (LOWER | UPPER | DIGIT | USCORE)*;
```

Now you have a single `ATOM` lexer rule that will give you an `ATOM` token to use in your rules.

This will result in simpler parser rules, but also, perhaps more importantly, a simpler ParseTree and *Context classes when you start dealing with your parse tree.

The revised grammar would be:

```
grammar Simple;

file: line ( EOL line)* EOL?;

line: U_INTEGER COLON list_of_atom;

empty_list: '[' ']';

list_of_atom: empty_list | '[' ATOM (',' ATOM)* ']';

U_INTEGER: DIGIT+;

DASH: '-';
DOT: '.';
SIGN: '+' | '-';
COLON: ':';
EOL: [\r\n];
BLANK: [\t ] -> skip;
ATOM:
    '\'' ('\\\'' | '\'\'' | ~'\'')* '\''
    | LOWER (LOWER | UPPER | DIGIT | USCORE)*;

fragment LOWER: [a-z];
fragment UPPER: [A-Z];
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
fragment USCORE: '_';
```

Passing this the input:

```
1 : [ 'a''b' ,  'a\'\'\'b'   , '\' ', ' ', 'atom with embedded spaces', ab_c]
```

Gives the following TokenStream:

```
[@0,0:0='1',<U_INTEGER>,1:0]
[@1,2:2=':',<':'>,1:2]
[@2,4:4='[',<'['>,1:4]
[@3,6:11=''a''b'',<ATOM>,1:6]
[@4,13:13=',',<','>,1:13]
[@5,16:25=''a\'\'\'b'',<ATOM>,1:16]
[@6,29:29=',',<','>,1:29]
[@7,31:35=''\' '',<ATOM>,1:31]
[@8,36:36=',',<','>,1:36]
[@9,38:40='' '',<ATOM>,1:38]
[@10,41:41=',',<','>,1:41]
[@11,43:69=''atom with embedded spaces'',<ATOM>,1:43]
[@12,70:70=',',<','>,1:70]
[@13,72:75='ab_c',<ATOM>,1:72]
[@14,76:76=']',<']'>,1:76]
[@15,77:76='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:77]
```

and this ParseTree:
[image]

Comment: For the "fused atom" I was just thinking that the second way of escaping a quote inside a quoted atom, namely: `''` (to be clear: "quote quote") looks _exactly_ like the case of two quoted atoms arranged in sequence, without any blanks in between - so why not create a parse tree node called "fused atoms" that can be postprocessed into a single atom later instead of adding special handling for this way of quote-quoting.

Comment: I suppose I will have a rule for an "unquoted atom" token as for `abc` for example (which needs no quotes). How does ANTLR decide which token applies? Does it take the first one which matches (no backtracking on later failure?) I'm just on the Chapter 4 of the ANTLR book.

Comment: I misread how you wanted to handle “quote quote”.  I’ll revise my answer to reflect what you actually said in your answer,  I would suggest, just handling that in the Lexer rule (it was simple).  It’ll be easier to deal with than post-processing multiple ATOM tokens.  (Obviously, you could do either, I’d just recommend what I have in my answer as “simpler”)

Comment: I’ll also revise to make changes for an “unquoted atom”.  You can either add it to the existing ATOM rule (striping the leading and trailing quotes would just do nothing, so it’s probably simple to keep it to one Lexer rule so you have only an ATOM token to write rules for.  UNQUOTED_ATOM would also work and is a matter of taste.   I’ll elaborate a bit in revised answer.  BTW... reading the ANTLR book is definitely the way to go.

Comment: OK, I've streamlined my answer to remove the (embarrassing) misreading of your "fused atom" intention.  And have also included my recommendation on how to handle unquoted atoms.  Some of this recommendation comes for "battlefield lessons" of knowing what challenges you'll potentially face with writing rules and dealing with the ParseTree.  (Don't use parser rules to recognize items you want to deal with as a single entity (changed: uinteger parser rule to U_INTEGER token, so you get a single token with the full Integer); avoid unnecessary parser rule levels (they impact your tree), etc.)

Comment: Looking good. So: "move more stuff to the lexer". And the order is important. This needs a bit of Junit code so that I be certain to remain on track while modifying the grammar.